# Screen shows only noise after resuming from inactivity

Tags: video, laptop, amd-ryzen

Just bought a new laptop (CPU Ryzen 2700, GPU Radeon vega 56), installed linux with KDE as desktop environments and mesa drivers.

Seems whenever I leave the laptop without any activity for some minutes and it shuts down the laptop screen, when I resume it, the screen keeps showing only noise (like a TV without signal) and am forced to forcefully shutdown the laptop. Happens also in other situations, e.g. if I switch to a tty and back it will sometimes also happen, but I haven’t been able to pinpoint how to reproduce it from switching ttys.

I’m wondering what could be the problem here and what to do about it. The issue is not present when running MS windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer myself: seems to be a problem with the suspend functionality (system is not able to recover from suspension). One way of "fixing" it is to disable all the actions that end up in suspend in the power management settings (e.g. in KDE's settings, section power management).